# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax when using if in one line

Tags: python

I tried running the accepted answer from [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort), but it gave me the following error:

```
File " < stdin >", line 4

convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text 


SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help please?

Thank you...

---

Update:
Thank you everyone for your responses.
I first integrated the code in my own script but received the error. Then I just tested this def on Python interactive window (just this line), and it gives same error.

I am using python/2.6.5. The strange thing is that this code runs on my other computer (Python 2.6.1). Is this code version-specific?

Comment: It works for me:
http://ideone.com/T76PlY

What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Can you post the entire error, and the Python version you're using (should be displayed when you start you interpreter)?

Comment: @root It's presumably copied and pasted from the answer he linked to. The line numbers match.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have edited my question. I am using python/2.6.5...

Comment: Be sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: @Makoto If he were, in a simple case like this that could only possibly cause an `IndentationError`, not a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: It's really the same script that I use on both computer, did not change anything. It works on one, but does not work on the other...

Comment: @fgar show the *full* traceback for the error. And, are you pretty sure you are not using an old python version on one of your computers?
The `if` expression was added in 2.5 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Bakuriu He's pasting the code straight into the interpreter, and it's causing a `Syntax Error`; that means this ***is*** the full traceback. Including the little `^` arrow pointing to the location of the syntax error, if present, might help, though.

Comment: Yes @Bakuriu, thanks, it's really my bad. I was using a machine with two Python installations on it, and when I thought I was using python/2.6.5, I was actually the other installation (2.4.3). Thanks for pointing out that the if expression was added in 2.5.

Comment: Thanks also @Mark Amery and everyone else for your help and responses!

Comment: Hi @Bakuriu, would you mind to post your comment as answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: @Bakuriu You're correct that it was added in 2.5. Here's a source: http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator

I suggest posting an answer, both for the record and to get some deserved rep. It was a nice question, especially given how most posters just assumed the asker was a moron when in fact there was a genuine problem. Well solved. :)

Answer (score -1):

The code below works in 2.6.x

```
import re

li = ['elm1', 'elm0', 'Elm18', 'elm9', 'elm10', 'Elm11', 'Elm12', 'elm13']

def natural_sort(l): 
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower() 
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ] 
    return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)

print natural_sort(li)
```

Try it again, with copy & paste.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. This code works on 2.6.x and above, but not on Python 2.4.x (at least on 2.4.3). I was using a machine with two Python installations on it, and when I thought I was using python/2.6.5, I was actually the other installation (2.4.3). Thanks!

Comment: @fgar I'd post your own answer and accept it, in that case, or invite Bakuriu to do so. This answer doesn't really contain the solution. :)

Comment: @Mark Amery, I think you're right. I'm sorry Excalibur, but thanks for your response